# Sabre- BARGAIN FINDER MAX (OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ) ResponseType=""

Tags: api, soap, sabre

I'm currently working on the development of Sabre SOAP API's for Air(Flights) and using BargainFinderMax(OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ) to search for flight availability. so in the request, there is a parameter **ResponseType**  that defines the type of response to the requested data. 
My Question is: if there is any responsetype which will bring the result grouped based upon the prices. ForExample: a group with one price = $1000 will contain multiple Options of flights (having different timings). For now, I can only get the OTA and GIR response type. which shows separate itineraries having the same price, as shown in the image below: 
[image]

It has two itineraries with the same data(same price) but different Legs. What I'm actually looking for is that Itineraries with same price be grouped together in a single element. 
Same as the response returned in TravelPort if we make LOWFARESEARCH Request and set SolutionResult="false". it gives **PricePoint** results i.e. Itineraries grouped in a single pricepoint. Can this be possible in sabre?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ResponseType can only have those 2 values, as stated in the request documentation: *ResponseType, specify type of the response, valid values: "OTA" - regular OTA response, "GIR" - Grouped Itinerary Response.*

If not used, it will default to OTA.

Anyway, even though it is harder to read (by a person), GIR groups almost everything, in order to avoid duplicating data. But, since the price of the whole itinerary is inside the itinerary element, the only way to do what you want is by looping through the itineraries and grouping them together, and it can be achieved using either OTA or GIR. There's nothing built in for that.

Comment: Yeah, I can construct the data based on GIR Response. But what I was actually looking for is if there is any possibility that the response is grouped based on prices. For Example: for One price i.e. $2000, there can be multiple solutions(itineraries) with different Departure/Arrival timings. Same as the response returned in TravelPort if we make LOWFARESEARCH Request and set SolutionResult="false". it gives Itineraries grouped in a single pricepoint. Can this be possible in sabre?

Comment: I might not be understanding the whole problem, because since nothing is repeated, then you should be able to get the different itineraries based on a specific price id.

Comment: Edited my question, have a look. and What Price Id you are speaking of ? 
can you give me the link to documentation for OTALowFARESEARCH RQ/RS with responseType = GIR??

Comment: I see what you mean, the price of the whole itinerary is inside the itinerary id, so the only way to do what you want is by looping through the itineraries and grouping them together. There's nothing built in for that. Sorry for the confusion :( I've updated the response to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I understood. Can you also provide me with all the API documentation regarding BFM using GIR, because I can't seem to find an appropriate **GIR request/response documentation** in _developer.sabre.com_

Comment: The request and response documentation was there. RQ: http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMaxRQ_v3-4-0_Design.xml RS: http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/GroupedItineraryResponse_v3.4.0_Design.xml